# How can I fill in turtle coordinates from a list using Python?

Tags: python, coordinates, fill, turtle-graphics

I need to know how I can fix this code up so that when the list called "redlist" is called which has a list of coordinates, it fills those points when  the move function is called. This is what I have so far:

```
redlist=[]
def move():
        penup()
        if color()[0]=="red":                      
        #coordinates of redlist should be filled here               

def paint():
        pendown()
        if color()[0]=="red":
                begin_fill
                redlist.append(pos())
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what coordinates you mean but I call them `x` and `y`

```
redlist=[]
def move():
        penup()
        if color()[0]=="red":                      
            x = 1 # replace this line
            y = 2 # replace this line
            redlist.append((x, y)) # you can access them by #x, y = redlist[-1]
        #coordinates of redlist should be filled here               

def paint():
        pendown()
        if color()[0]=="red":
                begin_fill
                redlist.append(pos())
```